# Dexpot's menu appears on Windows login

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop

I have used Dexpot in the past on Windows 10 with no troubles. It also works on my Windows 11 PC at work. I recently installed it on my home Windows 10 PC and now I'm seeing some odd behavior.

Soon after signing in to Windows, while all of my startup items are appearing, the Dexpot menu appears wherever my cursor happens to be. It's the same menu that appears when you right-click the tray icon. I can get rid of it by clicking on "Desktop 1", but it shouldn't appear at all.

Does anyone know why this is happening and, more importantly, how to stop it from happening?

[image]

Comment: Honestly, it’s probably, Windows 11.  There are two very different branches of Windows 11 at this point.  It working could have been a fluke

Comment: At my former employer, I was running Dexpot on a Microsoft Surface Studio 2 with Windows 10 and this anomaly never occurred. My current employer has set me up with the Windows 11 PC and, likewise, this anomaly has not occurred. So I know it works fine on both Windows 10 and 11. I just don't understand why it's happening on my home PC with Windows 10.

Comment: Windows 11 is prerelease software and should be expected to have bugs. Also, 3rd part software should be expected to have issues running in it.

Comment: Is no one actually reading the text of my post and/or comments? I've already stated multiple times--and I will restate here, with emphasis--**DEXPOT RUNS FINE ON WINDOWS 11**. The problem that I am having, shown in the screenshot is **IN WINDOWS 10**.